# Why the C# property initializer (new()) is written as that?

Tags: c#

```
    Info myPath = new Info()
    {
        path = oFile.FileName
    };
    ...
    class Info
    {
        public string path;
        public string Path
        {
            get { return path; }
            set { path = value; }
        }
    }
```

Above is the C# code from some program and it can work normally. But I don't understand it well. The first question is that why `path = oFile.FileName` is not written as `path = oFile.FileName;` ? Why the semicolon can be removed?

The second question is that why I cannot write it like this: `myPath.path = oFile.FileName` ? There will give error message by Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) to start

Comment: In addition to the above comments, have a look at [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx). See in the first example that the properties (with their corresponding values) are separated by commas and that the last property has no semicolon.

Comment: The term to google for here is "object initializer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That construct is an [*object initializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx). It's not a list of arbitrary statements - it's *only* initialization of fields and properties, and they're comma-separated:

```
Foo x = new Foo // Implicitly calls the parameterless constructor
{
    Property1 = value1,
    Property2 = value2
};
```

That's shorthand for:

```
Foo tmp = new Foo();
tmp.Property1 = value1;
tmp.Property2 = value2;
Foo x = tmp;
```

Object initializers were introduced in C# 3, along with *collection initializers* which are effectively syntactic sugar for repeated calls to `Add`. So:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>
{
    "Foo", "Bar"
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
tmp.Add("Foo");
tmp.Add("Bar");
List<string> names = tmp;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have many ways of initializing an object in C#.
Here you can do what you have written, which will be an equivalent to this:

```
Info myPath = new Info();
myPath.Path = oFile.FileName;
```

this syntax

```
Info myPath = new Info()
{
    path = oFile.FileName
};
```

is just a shortcut, and can be more readable, but will do the same thing. Actually it seems that it was kind of taken from VisualBasic (the `With` statement).

To explain the above syntax:

```
YourClassName <your_variable> = new YourClassName() 
{ 
    <property_name> = value,
    <anotherProperty> = value, 
    ... 
    <last_property> = value 
};
```

the last way is to have a constructor that takes the path as an argument and initializes it. This is actually the way where there is the less operations done by the cpu (but it's not significant).

Answer (score 2):

In C# 3.0, they added a new & helpful feature for initializing objects as a single statement/expression.

Whereas before, you'd have to issue separate statements:

```
Info myPath = new Info();
myPath.Filename = ...
myPath.AnotherProperty = ...
myPath.AnotherAnotherProperty = ...
```

You can now perform the same assignments in one step:

```
Info myPath = new Info
{
    Filename = ...
    AnotherProperty = ...
    AnotherAnotherProperty = ...
};
```

This is especially useful, for constructing objects in Linq queries (without having to custom-code object constructors).

For example:

```
someList.Select(x => new SomethingElse{ SomeProperty = x.Something });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Info myPath = new Info()
    {
        path = oFile.FileName
    };
```

means:
Initialize a new Info Class and add to property path the value oFile.FileName
it is the short version of:

```
Info myPath = new Info();
myPath.path = oFile.FileName;
```

you do not need ';' because you can stack more properties in the brackets like this:

```
Person p = new Person()
{
Name = "John",
Age = 25
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C# allows you to initialize properties of an object at the same time that you're constructing it.

These are all equivalent:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Property = "Bar";
foo.AnotherProperty = 12;


var foo = new Foo()
{
    Property = "Bar",
    AnotherProperty = 12
};


// The parentheses are not really necessary for parameterless constructors
var foo = new Foo
{
    Property = "Bar",
    AnotherProperty = 12
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the new way of initializing variables in C#. You can also skip '()' signs.
You can initialize like that also lists, arrays, etc. in brackets you must insert elements which you want to initialize in your object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Info myPath = new Info()
{
    path = oFile.FileName
};
```

is equivalent to

```
Info myPath = new Info();
myPath.path = oFile.FileName;
```

When initializing with the object initializing structure, you create a list of property assignments as you noted. This way you can create objects and assign variables in one call without having an explicit constructor. The above could easily have been written in one line.

More info can be found [on the MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx).